# Consuming Rest, DAO or Service layer?

Tags: rest, layers, dao

I feel like this is a dumb question but here it goes:
If i'm consuming rest (getting data and transforming in POJO), does it sit in the DAO or Service layer?
As for what i've researched I believe that it should be in Service Layer but i couldn't find a definitive answer or explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649786/dao-and-service-layer-design) as reference.

basically what one **should** do is use the service layer to expose `DAO` functionality thus,

- it won't expose your `DAO` layer to the front end of your
  application.
- It will also grant you the ability to provide extra functionality to
  the methods provided by your `DAO` layer.
- Having your service layer will allow you to query your `DAO` layer
  through the service layer, making it much more easier to interface
  with your application.

Basically, one **should** use the `DAO` to deal with all the database staff (CRUD) operations while the Service layer is used to communicate with the DAO, adapt the data returned by the `DAO` and handle it without exposing the `DAO`.

`DAO` is here to represent all the database operations that your DB is available to perform.